# Importing Data from Mulitple access database files to Ms Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Am working on  a project where a  user has to **import multiple access database files** (up to 20 mdb files at once ) with same table structure into **Ms SQL server** where the system links  with the data for further Analysis. i would like a most efficient way of accomplishing this task (using c#, Ms Sql Server) , without consuming too much time while exporting data to sql server. i have not done this before, so can you kindly guide me through.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If this needs to be run in an automated fashion, you should write an SSIS package and schedule it as a job.  If it needs to be run once, you can just use the Import wizard in SQL Server.

Comment: i read the SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) but it seems you need to install SSIS on same machine where your app runs which doesn't  confer with my case where the application  must run on any users machine who has the installation. Also a user has to link  those access files manually  by selecting  files of his or her choice ( those access datasets are populated with data depending on geographical locations, so a user may opt to analyse 5 datasets out of 30 possible regions, so he/she should be able to import those datasets to sql server, where the system picks the data for analysis)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out SQL Server Integration Services ([SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services)).  There are some answers on StackOverflow already (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709670/how-do-i-import-ms-access-data-into-sql-server-using-ssis-package)) that show how to use SSIS to move data from Access to SQL Server.

If you build an SSIS package you could call it repeatedly from a C# program and set the parameters (path to the Access database file, table name, etc).  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michen/archive/2007/03/22/running-ssis-package-programmatically.aspx) for an example.