# SQL Job failed because driver is not valid

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, ssis, odbc

I have a SSIS package that I want to schedule in a job in SQL Server 2008, the package runs perfectly by it's own, but when executed in a job it fails, I get the following error message:

> Executed as user: XXXXXXX \ SYSTEM. Execute Package Utility for Microsoft (R) SQL Server Version 10.0.4000.0 for 64-bit
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.
>   Started: 10:48:09 AM Error: 18/06/2014 10:48:09.42
>   Code: 0xC0047062 Source: Data Flow Task ADO NET Source [1]
>   Description: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [HY024] [Microsoft] [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] '(unknown)' is not a valid path.
>   Make sure That the path name is spelled Correctly and That you are connected to the server on Which the file reside.
>   ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager]
>   SQLSetConnectAttr error ERROR [HY024] driver [Microsoft] [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] '(unknown)' is not a valid path.
>   Make sure That the path name is spelled Correctly and That you are connected to the server on Which the file reside.
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError (OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle .. ctor (OdbcConnection connection, built OdbcConnectionString, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle)
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen .. ctor (OdbcConnection outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString ConnectionOptions)
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection (DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DBConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection (DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection (DbConnection owningConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection (DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory ConnectionFactory)
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open ()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ManagedHelper.GetManagedConnection (AssemblyQualifiedName String, String connStr, Object transaction)
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManager100.AcquireConnection at (Object pTransaction)
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.AcquireConnections at (Object transaction)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostAcquireConnections(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Object transaction)
>   End Error Error: 18/06/2014 10:48:09.42
>   Code: 0xC0047017
>   Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
>   Description: Error in validating component "ADO NET Source" (1); error code 0x80131937 was returned.
>   End Error Error: 18/06/2014 10:48:09.42
>   Code: 0xC004700C
>   Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
>   Description: Failed to validate one or more components.
>   End Error Error: 18/06/2014 10:48:09.42
>   Code: 0xC0024107
>   Source: Data Flow Task
>   Description: There were errors during task validation.
>   End DTExec error: package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
>   Started: 10:48:09 AM Finished: 10:48:09 AM Elapsed: 0.219 seconds.
>   Package execution failed. Unable to perform the step.

What the package does is to get data from a Microsoft Access data base inside a network drive(Z:) from a another server. And past the data to a table in a SQL data base.

The drivers and the server where I'm at are 64 bits, and I tried to run it with the "32 bit runtime" option in the job properties but I get the same message, and I do not really know what to do, I tracked the code errors on google but I don't find any solution. And as far as I know there shouldn't be any permissions problems, since in the server where I'm trying to create this job there's only one user and it's the administrator and also there are other jobs created by the same user, so I believe proxies are not needed , but this one is the only one that uses an Access ODBC.

If there's anything that I should check, please tell me.I really don't know what to do, I've been trying to get this thing working for almost a month and nothing. So if anyone could help me, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Is the Z: Drive mapped on the server where your package is deployed?

Comment: try using network drive fully qualified path, like with IP \\10.50.1.2\sharedFolder\File  or with server name \\server\share\file_path

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I can run the package just fine independently, and the Z: drive is listed on the windows explorer with all the other drives. How exactly can I assure that the Z drive is mapped?

Comment: is Z: drive belongs to your local hard drive or mapped to any shared folder over network

Comment: @Vikramsinh Shinde Where do I use that path? I created a connection with the ODBC manager to the Access data base, and I was able to connect to successfully using that connection in the SSIS package. I didn't had to type any paths directly.

Comment: @Vikramsinh Shind is a network drive from another server

Comment: Create new ODBC connection, choose provider  as Access database Engine. It will provide you the facility to enter access database file name. At this place instead Z: , use fully qualified network drive path

Comment: @Vikramsinh Shind I did it and it didn't change anything

Comment: if the issue is with ODBC, you can achieve same with ADO.net or OLE DB . http://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/upload-data-from-ms-access-database-to-sql-server-ssis/      http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2656/simple-step-by-step-process-to-import-ms-access-data-into-sql-server-using-ssis/    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709670/how-do-i-import-ms-access-data-into-sql-server-using-ssis-package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating ODBC system sources you need to replace the network drive with the full path See this [link](https://support.tracerplus.com/article/230-modifying-an-ms-access-odbc-datasource-in-windows-to-point-to-a-full-unc-path)