# How to import multiple Access tables into SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access, ssis

I have an Access database with almost 100 tables. How can I import them all at once into a SQL Server database using SSIS (not using the import data wizard in SQL Server).

I'm able to import the tables individually by creating a task for each, but I do not see an option to select all of the tables.

Comment: This should help you do what you want to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709670/how-do-i-import-ms-access-data-into-sql-server-using-ssis-package

Answer (score -1):

In my own experience that iv'e done before,
There's an option.. import it using excel file. But you need to put specific column name in excel..

Hope it helps..